# Ubuntu 17.04 Live USB: end Kernel panic

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, kernel, 17.04

I made an Ubuntu 17.04 Live USB using Startup Disk Creator in order to install Ubuntu on my Laptop/tablet hybrid, then once I booted it on that device and selected "Try Ubuntu without installing" I got the following:

```
[   10.665438] Initramfs unpacking failed: LZMA data is corrupt
[   10.837266] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,0)
[   10.837361] CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.10.0-19-generic #21-Ubuntu
[   10.837442] Hardware name: LENOVO 80SG/Cavalli, BIOS 1HCN31WW 06/02/2016
[   10.837511] Call Trace:
[   10.837548]  dump_stack+0x63/0x81
[   10.837588]  panic+0xe4/022d
[   10.837625]  mount_block_root+0x1fd/0x2bc
[   10.837670]  ? set_debug_rodata+0x12/0x12
[   10.837714]  mount_root+0x33/0x35
[   10.837752]  prepare_namespace+0x134/0x189
[   10.837797]  kernel_init_freeable+0x21e/0x249
[   10.837846]  ? rest_init+0x80/0x80
[   10.837884]  kernel_init+0xe/0x100
[   10.837924]  ret_from_fork+0x2c/0x40
[   10.838114] Kernel Offset: 0x3d600000 from 0xffffffff8100000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff8000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[   10.838226] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,0)
```

Then I tried booting it on the machine that I created the USB on, which has Ubuntu 17.04 already installed and running just fine, and I got the same result (except for the device name obviously).
I also tried burning the ISO onto the USB using Disks, but I got the same exact result on both devices.
Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

The device I am installing it on is a Lenovo MIIX 310, which successfully booted 16.04 from the same USB stick. I might install 16.04, then upgrade through it, but I prefer to install 17.04 as I already have the ISO.

Comment: Mos tlikely a bad download or bad burn. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I would say it is a bad download because I used a torrent to download it.

Comment: Check the sum. Torrents are usually very reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a bad ISO. Re-downloaded and fixed this problem.